# Pythonのconvolve2dについて

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Pythonで`convolve2d`を使う下記のプログラムをかきました。

```
#coding:utf-8

import numpy as np
from scipy import signal


a = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    [7,8,9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16,17,18],
    [19,20,21,22,23,24],
    [25,26,27,28,29,30],
    [31,32,33,34,35,36]
    ])

f = np.array([
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ])

print a
print f
p = signal.convolve2d(a, f, 'valid')
print p
```

結果は

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16 17 18]
 [19 20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29 30]
 [31 32 33 34 35 36]]
[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
[[14 15 16 17]
 [20 21 22 23]
 [26 27 28 29]
 [32 33 34 35]]
```

このようになりました。

この[サイト](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/ja/plug-in-convmatrix.html)を参考にすると畳み込み演算は元の行列の右上、左上、右下、左下を除くすべての点における近傍8ピクセルとフィルタの要素をそれぞれ掛けて足してその結果を新しい行列上のフィルタの中心座標にセットするようなので行列が1行下がると考えられましたが、結果を見ると上がっているように見えます。
更に`valid`を`same`にすると

```
[[ 7  8  9 10 11]
 [13 14 15 16 17]
 [19 20 21 22 23]
 [25 26 27 28 29]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]
```

このようになります。
これはどちらが正しいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

リンク先と同じ計算をするにはcross-correlateで計算します。

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal


a = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    [7,8,9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16,17,18],
    [19,20,21,22,23,24],
    [25,26,27,28,29,30],
    [31,32,33,34,35,36]
    ])

f = np.array([
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ])

print a
print f
p = signal.correlate(a, f, 'same')
print p
```

**出力**

期待通り(?)一つ下がっています。

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16 17 18]
 [19 20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29 30]
 [31 32 33 34 35 36]]
[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16 17 18]
 [19 20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29 30]]
```

## Convolutionについて

Convolutionは電気信号にフィルターを適用した時の波形を求めるのによく使われるそうです(大学の授業以来なので分かったようなことは書けませんが)。画像に対するフィルターは縦横に拡張したものと同等です。

信号gに対してフィルターfを適用するとき、過去の信号をフィルターした結果と、より最近の信号をフィルターした結果が重なることから、出力yは次のようになります。要するに過去の積み重ねで、scipyもこの定義に従っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Cross-Correlation([相互相関関数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%B8%E4%BA%92%E7%9B%B8%E9%96%A2%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0))はtauの符号が逆さまになっています。コンボユーションではフィルターを逆方向から当てていて、Cross-Correlationでは順方向に当てていることになり、それがシフトした方向の違いの理由でした。

参考までにscipyを使わないコンボリューションの実装との比較を示します。１次元のみ。パディングの代わりに周囲は無限の0の信号とフィルターになっています。scipyではfullモードが一番近いです。

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # t, t+1, t+2, ...
F = [1,0,0] #t, t-1, t-2, ...

def g(t):
    "signal at time t"
    if t < 0 or t >= len(A):
        return 0
    return A[t]

def f(t):
    "stationary filter function"
    if t < 0 or t >= len(F):
        return 0
    return F[t]

def y(t):
    s = 0
    for tau in range(t+1):
        s += f(t-tau)*g(tau)
        # 可換なので次でも同じ
        # s += f(tau)*g(t-tau)
    return s

# 二つの配列がギリギリ重ね合わさった時の長さ
l = len(A) + len(F)   
print [y(t) for t in range(l+1)]

# scipy version
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
a = np.array([A])
f = np.array([F])
p = signal.convolve2d(a, f, 'full')
print p
```

実行結果

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0]]
```

参考リンク
[人生畳み込み](http://www.ice.tohtech.ac.jp/~nakagawa/laplacetrans/convolution1.htm) (積分が苦手な人向け)
[SciPy correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html)
[NumPy convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) (離散の定義sum(a[m]*v[n-m])が載っている。本質的に上の積分と同じ)

Comment: まったく別の計算なんですね。2次元についてどのような計算をしているのか考えてみましたが、フィルターを右下から、元の行列を左上からそれぞれ掛けてたして、最後にそれを行列の左上の値とするということで合っていますか?

Comment: 上下にシフトした理由を訂正しました。相互相関関数は広い意味で畳み込みの一種なので、畳み込みと呼ばれている例も多いようです。特にフィルターが左右対称の場合は順方向に当てても逆方向に当てても同じ結果になりますね。２次元の場合はf(t-tau)*g(t)をf(x-j,y-k)*g(x, y)のように拡張してj,kで二重積分します。x,y,j,kで4重forループでsum(sum(f(x-j,y-k)*g(x, y)))を求めることになります。